# Getting stack traces on Unix systems, automatically

Tags: linux, unix, stack-trace, segmentation-fault

What methods are there for automatically getting a stack trace on Unix systems? I don't mean just getting a core file or attaching interactively with GDB, but having a SIGSEGV handler that dumps a backtrace to a text file.

Bonus points for the following optional features:

- Extra information gathering at crash time (eg. config files).
- Email a crash info bundle to the developers.
- Ability to add this in a `dlopen`ed shared library
- Not requiring a GUI

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on systems with the BSD [`backtrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace) functionality available (Linux, OSX 1.5, BSD of course), you can do this programmatically in your signal handler.

For example ([`backtrace` code derived from IBM example](http://www-128.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-cppexcep.html?ca=dgr-lnxw07ExceptionTricks)):

```c
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    void * array[25];
    int nSize = backtrace(array, 25);
    char ** symbols = backtrace_symbols(array, nSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < nSize; i++)
    {
        puts(symbols[i]);;
    }

    free(symbols);

    signal(sig, &sig_handler);
}

void h()
{
    kill(0, SIGSEGV);
}

void g()
{
    h();
}

void f()
{
    g();
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, &sig_handler);
    f();
}
```

Output:

```
0   a.out                               0x00001f2d sig_handler + 35
1   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x95f8f09b _sigtramp + 43
2   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
3   a.out                               0x00001fb1 h + 26
4   a.out                               0x00001fbe g + 11
5   a.out                               0x00001fcb f + 11
6   a.out                               0x00001ff5 main + 40
7   a.out                               0x00001ede start + 54
```

This doesn't get bonus points for the optional features (except not requiring a GUI), however, it does have the advantage of being very simple, and not requiring any additional libraries or programs.

Comment: This works as a toy example (e.g. when you cause the SIGSEGV manually) but will probably _not_ work when you need it the most. See @Gilad Ben-Yossef's answer.

Answer (score 15):

FYI,

the suggested solution (using backtrace_symbols in a signal handler) is dangerously broken. DO NOT USE IT -

Yes, backtrace and backtrace_symbols will produce a backtrace and a translate it to symbolic names, however:

1. backtrace_symbols allocates memory using malloc and you use free to free it -  If you're crashing because of memory corruption your malloc arena is very likely to be corrupt  and cause a double fault.
2. malloc and free protect the malloc arena with a lock internally. You might have faulted in the middle of a malloc/free with the lock taken, which will cause these function or anything that calls them to dead lock.
3. You use puts which uses the standard stream, which is also protected by a lock. If you faulted in the middle of a printf you once again have a deadlock.
4. On 32bit platforms (e.g. your normal PC of 2 year ago), the kernel will plant a return address to an internal glibc function instead of your faulting function in your stack, so the single most important piece of information you are interested in - in which function did the program fault, will actually be corrupted on those platform.

So, the code in the example is the worst kind of wrong - it LOOKS like it's working, but it will really fail you in unexpected ways in production.

BTW, interested in doing it right? check [this](http://tuxology.net/lectures/crash-and-burn-writing-linux-application-fault-handlers/) out.

Cheers,
Gilad.

Comment: I'm not terribly versed in the area. But if you fork and execute the backtracing in the child process you could get away with, no?

Comment: @LiquidityC If you `fork()` inside your signal handler, your child process will be in the same situation as the process you just forked. `fork()` in a signal handler is probably most useful if followed by `execv()`/`execve()` otherwise you've just forked something borked.

Comment: Strangely, answers are meant to contain an answer to the question asked. Not to explain to never apply other answers which are working in 99% of cases or to post broken links. So just please include your solution here.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how to get some more info using a demangler. As you can see this one also logs the stacktrace to file.

```c
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cxxabi.h>

void sig_handler(int sig)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    void * array[25];
    int nSize = backtrace(array, 25);
    char ** symbols = backtrace_symbols(array, nSize);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int status;
        char *realname;
        std::string current = symbols[i];
        size_t start = current.find("(");
        size_t end = current.find("+");
        realname = NULL;
        if (start != std::string::npos && end != std::string::npos) {
            std::string symbol = current.substr(start+1, end-start-1);
            realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(symbol.c_str(), 0, 0, &status);
        }
        if (realname != NULL)
            stream << realname << std::endl;
        else
            stream << symbols[i] << std::endl;
        free(realname);
    }
    free(symbols);
    std::cerr << stream.str();
    std::ofstream file("/tmp/error.log");
    if (file.is_open()) {
        if (file.good())
            file << stream.str();
        file.close();
    }
    signal(sig, &sig_handler);
}
```

Comment: using C++ in signal handlers - bug in genome.

Comment: @vitaly.v.ch The bug is not so much the use of C++ as the use of a multitude of signal unsafe functions. Anything that allocates memory is pretty much guaranteed _not_ to work when you most want it to. Sure, it will look ok if you `kill -11 <pid>` but if that's what's crashing your code, just stop doing it...

Answer (score 2):

Dereks solution is probably the best, but here's an alternative anyway:

Recent Linux kernel version allow you to pipe core dumps to a script or program. You could write a script to catch the core dump, collect any extra information you need and mail everything back. 
This is a global setting though, so it'd apply to any crashing program on the system. It will also require root rights to set up.
It can be configured through the /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern file. Set that to something like ' | /home/myuser/bin/my-core-handler-script'.

The Ubuntu people use this feature as well.