# Crash reporting in C for Linux

Tags: c, linux, crashrpt

Following this question:
[Good crash reporting library in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49224/good-crash-reporting-library-in-c)

Is there any library like CrashRpt.dll that does the same on Linux?  That is, generate a failure report including a core dump and any necessary environment and notify the developer about it?

Edit: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265/getting-stack-traces-on-unix-systems-automatically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See *[Getting stack traces on Unix systems, automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265/getting-stack-traces-on-unix-systems-automatically)* on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't mean to rain on your parade, I intended this link as a supplementary resource. I'm still interested in ways to get the backtrace back to the developers (eg. kerneloops.org). So far it seems like gathering the environment and associated data is up to the individual developer.

Answer (score 2):

Compile your code with debug symbols, enter unlimit coredumpsize in your shell and you'll get a coredump in the same folder as the binary. Use gdb/ddd - open the program first and then open the core dump. You can check [this](http://www.agsrhichome.bnl.gov/Controls/doc/crashFiles/crashFiles.html) out for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

@Ionut
This handles generating the core dump, but it doesn't handle notifying the developer when other users had crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Note:  there are two interesting registers in an `x86` seg-fault crash.

The first, **EIP**, specifies the code address at which the exception occurred.  In RichQ's answer, he uses addr2line to show the source line that corresponds to the crash address.  But EIP can be invalid; if you call a function pointer that is null, it can be `0x00000000`, and if you corrupt your call stack, the return can pop any random value into EIP.

The second, **CR2**, specifies the data address which caused the segmentation fault.  In RichQ's example, he is setting up i as a null pointer, then accessing it.  In this case, CR2 would be `0x00000000`.  But if you change:

```
int j = *i
```

to:

```
int j = i[2];
```

Then you are trying to access address `0x00000008`, and that's what would be found in CR2.

Comment: Note that CR2 is actually the linear address of the faulting access, while 0x00000008 is the virtual offset. If the segment base is non-zero, the two will be different, and CR2 will report *segment_base+0x00000008*.

Answer (score 0):

Nathan, under what circumstances in a segment base non-zero?  I've never seen that occur in my 5 years of Linux application development.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin

I do architectural validation for x86, so I'm *very* familiar with the architecture the processor provides, but *very un*familiar with how it's used.  That's what I based my comment on.  If CR2 can be counted on to give the correct answer, then I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Nathan, I wasn't insisting that you were incorrect; I was just saying that in my (limited) experience with Linux, the segment base is always zero.  Maybe that's a good question for me to ask...